# htaccess redirect then rewrite a url to make it pretty

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have the url because that is where the file is actually found:

```
www.example.com/bla/annoying/long.php
```

I redirect a nicer url to the above url with a 301.

```
redirect 301 /niceee http://www.example.com/bla/annoying/long.php
```

so now when people goto www.example.com/niceee it redirects to the correct page... but the thing is, once the redirection has occurred, it ends up as the annoying long url again.

so they goto www.example.com/niceee and end up at http://www.example.com/bla/annoying/long.php

How do I make it redirect and rewrite the url to **/niceee** ?

1. so they goto www.example.com/niceee
2. The content of http://www.example.com/bla/annoying/long.php is shown
3. but the url remains as www.example.com/niceee

Comment: Do you mean redirect 301 /bla/annoying/long http ://www.example.com/niceee ?

Comment: I've rewritten the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^niceee/? /bla/annoying/long.php [L,NC]
```

With this rule:

1. Users will go to www.example.com/niceee
2. The content of /bla/annoying/long.php will be shown
3. url in the browser remains as `www.example.com/niceee`

Comment: That's spot on dude! Thanksss and it makes sense too! htaccess seems as cryptic as reg expressions... i'm crying here. :)

Comment: @JamesT: lol :) you're welcome, glad it worked. `mod_rewrite` is probably as much fun as the `regex`.

Comment: use [L] only if it's Last rule, you want to be applied.
And secondly, I suggest using [QSA] modifier as well. (it appends whatewer is after ? in first url to second url)

Comment: @Nikes: No `QSA` isn't needed here. That is applicable only when rule modifies query string. Query String is automatically carried over.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but learning, what it does now can save some headache for @JamesT when changing the rule later - with using some param, or MVC framework or whatever :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use relative URL for not being redirected,
like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /niceee /bla/annoying/long
```

this way /niceee stays in the adress bar, but the content is shown from /bla/annoying/long

Comment: Can't seem to get that to work, ive reworked the question... can you see if it helps solve the problem?

Comment: That's *not* a relative URL. It's absolute because it starts with /. By not giving an explicit code, and not giving `http://domain`, it should be a 200 code and NOT sent back to the browser or search engine. Nike's example has an error: omit the / from /niceee. You might also want to use ^ and possibly $ in the pattern to limit what gets matched: `^niceee$`